# Difference between the queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables which I am using in sub queries like below.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE (X,Y) NOT IN (SELECT X,Y FROM TABLE_A));
```

But it took ages to run the query as the tables have 400,000 to 500,000 rows. [image: High_cost]

Whereas, when I do the below query, it doesn't take much time.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE X||Y NOT IN (SELECT X||Y FROM TABLE_A));
```

[image: Low_cost]
I got a doubt whether both are same or not after seeing the execution time.

1. Why is one slower than the other?
2. Are these queries same?

Comment: Well the queries are clearly not the same !  Run an explain plan on each of them and let’s see the execution plans.

Comment: They should give same result. It may happen, second one is following index. Could you pls check index structure of TABLE_B , TABLE_C ? Also pls run explain plan on both to see why they are behaving in such a way. its odd because as far as i have seen first one should perform better. but again, all depends on data + index.

Comment: I have updated the query. It was "not in". And also TABLE_C changed to TABLE_A. Copied wrong query. TABLE_A does have an index on 4 columns. Column X is 1st and Column Y is 3rd in order. TABLE_B doesn't have an index. I will update plan in a while after connecting to work.

Comment: @BobC I've added the plans.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yeah correct. Silly me. Corrected remaining but didn't notice this. Corrected again.

Comment: Please edit your question to tag only the db platform in question. Oracle and MySQL are two different database platforms.

Comment: Remove the insert clause, it is irrelevant. Run autotrace on both of them to compare the executions startistics and identifying bottlenecks. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/03/why-is-my-sql-slow-go-faster-features/

Comment: They are not the same if either X or Y can be null, or if `X||Y` can be ambiguous, for example `X||Y` = `'ABC'` when X = `'A'` and Y = `'BC'` or if X = `AB'` and Y = `'C'` etc.

Comment: @Tegiri Nenashi , the problem is with insert. When I use the select statement alone, both are fast. But on insert, one is becoming slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
The key here is the "INTERNAL FUNCTION" in the plan, which probably means you are comparing columns with different data types (which is always a bad idea)

For example


SQL> create table t1 ( x int, y int );

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 ( x varchar2(10), y varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t1 select rownum,rownum from dual
  2  connect by level <= 1000;

1000 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t2 select rownum,rownum from dual
  2  connect by level <= 1000;

1000 rows created.

SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain
SQL> select *
  2  from t1
  3  where (x,y) not in (select x,y from t2);

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2177415756

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |  1000 | 16000 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN ANTI NA |      |  1000 | 16000 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   SORT JOIN         |      |  1000 |  8000 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |  1000 |  8000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   SORT UNIQUE       |      |  1000 |  8000 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2   |  1000 |  8000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("X")=TO_NUMBER("X") AND
              INTERNAL_FUNCTION("Y")=TO_NUMBER("Y"))
       filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("Y")=TO_NUMBER("Y") AND
              INTERNAL_FUNCTION("X")=TO_NUMBER("X"))
```

We had to clean up the data types before we could do a proper join, and hence we did not use the hash join.

When you changed this to be concatentation, that operator made everything a string, and hence a hash join could be used.

```
SQL> select *
  2  from t1
  3  where (x||y) not in (select x||y from t2);

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1275484728

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |   990 | 15840 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN ANTI NA |      |   990 | 15840 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |  1000 |  8000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2   |  1000 |  8000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access(TO_CHAR("X")||TO_CHAR("Y")="X"||"Y")

SQL>
```

but as William has pointed out, you run the risk of inaccurate results.

Comment: both tables are similar. I checked the data types as well. X is VARCHAR2(5 CHAR) and Y is VARCHAR2(15 CHAR).

Comment: If you get a full plan using DBMS_XPLAN which shows the notes/filter/predicates, then we'll know exactly what internal function is being used